# Laravel - Retrieve records from many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have three tables in many to many relationship

```
┌─────────────────┐          ┌─────────────────┐          ┌──────────────────┐
│ users           │          │ department_user │          │ departments      │
├─────────────────┤          ├─────────────────┤          ├──────────────────┤
| id              |          | id              |          | id               |
| name            |          | user_id         |          | name             |
└─────────────────┘          | department_id   |          └──────────────────┘
                             | joined_at       |          
                             └─────────────────┘
```

Departments table

```
1 | department 1
2 | department 2
3 | department 3
```

Users table

```
1| Mark
2| Jack
```

Department_user table

```
Id | user_id | department_id | joined_at
1  |    1    |      1        | 2019-01-01 
2  |    2    |      1        | 2019-03-26
3  |    1    |      1        | 2019-04-01
4  |    1    |      3        | 2019-05-01
```

User Model:

```
public function departments()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Department)->withPivot('joined_at');
}
```

Department Model:

```
public function users()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('joined_at');
}
```

DepartmentController :

```
$department = Department::with(['phones', 'users' => function($query)
{
  $query->orderBy('joined_at', 'desc');
}])->get();
return view('dashboard.departments.show', compact('department'));
```

Show.blade :

```
<h3>{{  department->name }}</h3><span>{{ $department->users->count() }}</span>
@foreach ($department->users as $user)
   <li>
      {{ $user-> name }} 
      {{ $user-> departments->last()->pivot->joined_at }}
   </li>
 @endforeach
```

What I want is to list users like this

Department 1

```
1 users
Jack  –   joined_at 2019-03-26
```

Department 3

```
1 users
Mark   –   joined_at 2019-05-01
```

But the result I got is

Department 1

```
3 users
Mark   –   joined_at 2019-01-01
Jack  –   joined_at 2019-03-26
Mark   –   joined_at 2019-04-01
```

Department 3

```
1 users
Mark   –   joined_at 2019-05-01
```

So I want to list the last users in certain department and count of them but ignore duplicates if user where in that department in previous dates

Answer (score 0):

If you want a **Many to Many** relation to have no duplicates, just remove the `Id` column from the `department_user` table, then make the primary key of the table a combination of `user_id` and `department_id`.

This will allow you to avoid duplicates in the future.

Comment: I will need this duplicate later to know the user history in departments

Comment: Okay, so you would like to know the most recent `join_date`, or the earliest `join_date`?

Comment: I want to know the most recent `join_date`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Department::join('department_user','department_user.department_id','=','departments.id')
->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'department_user.user_id')
->selectRaw('users.id, COUNT(*) AS count, MAX(joined_at) AS joined_at')
->groupBy('department_user.user_id')
->having('count', '<', 2)  // ignore duplicates
->orderBy('joined_at', 'desc')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$department = Department::with(['phones', 'users' => function($query)
{
$query->orderBy('joined_at', 'desc');
}])->get();
```

and before you loop the departments

```
$department->users->groupBy('name');
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.name'